# SSRS re-sorts data meticulously sorted from the SQL query! Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, reporting-services

I'm writing up a report using SQL Server Reporting Service via Visual Studio 2008. I have a stored procedure on a SQL Server database that returns a list in which I need the entry with value "`F`" in colulmn `[Column]` to be always on top, as such:

```
F
A
B
C
D
E
G
H
```

The order of the others does not matter, so I accomplished this feat with the following in-query clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE [Column] WHEN 'F' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

The stored procedure returns with the proper sort if I play it in SQL Server Management Studio, and it also works properly when I call it from the Report Data Query Designer window.

**HOWEVER...** when I go to preview the report, the elements are re-sorted alphabetically in the matrix in which they are contained, so that "`A`" is on top and "`F`" is in between "`E`" and "`G`":

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

I found [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254604/why-does-my-sql-server-reporting-service-ssrs-report-appear-to-re-sort-the-d), but on inspection the matrix contains no sorting options. I think it might have at one point, in which case maybe something is not refreshing properly (though the stored procedure has been altered to return different data and the new entries appeared successfully, so I don't think that's it).

Any ideas for what I can try? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache of the report (the *.rdl.data) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked **both** the Tablix Properties **and** the Column Group properties for sorting? The Column Grouping's sort takes Priority...and additionally will automatically include a clause to sort on the same field that the Group is on, which usually accounts for confusion like this in my experience.